# pod install flutter failure

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods 1.7.5 ,when I execute `pod install`, I'm getting this error :

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass.
 #  from /Users/yuhan/jiemian_project/iOS_MoerFinance/A-源代码/MoerFinance/Podfile:71
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    location = flutter_podhelper.index(post_install_string)
 >    location += post_install_string.length
 #    
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Did anyone face the same problem before?I don't know why `flutter_podhelper.index(post_install_string)`return nil,I can find `podhelper`in the directory.In another computer, `pod install`is success, but in this computer, show the error above.

podfile some code

```
def multiple_post_install(flutter_application_path)
  #read podhelper from flutter_application_path
  flutter_podhelper = File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb'))

  #find the post_install end location by hardcoding
  post_install_string = 'post_install do |installer|'
  location = flutter_podhelper.index(post_install_string)
  location += post_install_string.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It  will resolve this issue

1- Upgrade flutter (make sure to always point master channel else switch to master channel)
2- update cocoapods
3- flutter clean
4- rm -Rf ios/Pods
5- rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
6- rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
7- rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec

build again and check